# cypress unable to click login button. getting Post error

Tags: cypress

New to cypress. Getting error in cypress login click.

```js
it('Should Login', () => {
  cy.get('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_m_btnSubmit').click()
})
```

Error Screenshot

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have is coming from the app itself, it looks like the login is failing.

You set credentials user name and password before login, and the screenshot shows a previous test where password is entered.

Try combining all the login steps into one test. Cypress does a lot of clearing of data between tests to make them independent, so each test should be an "atomic" action, for example

```js
it('Should Login', () => {
  cy.get('#username').type('myusername')
  cy.get('#password').type('mypassword')
  cy.get('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_m_btnSubmit').click()
})
```

Comment: It worked and really thank you for the answer. I spend lot of time ( 3 days continously) in searching and dealing this issue. Infact searching is one way it is good that one will learn more about the tool and in other way it demotimates to move forward. I was wondering, when I did manually it worked and why not it worked when i use cypress. Now that i know by combining all steps into one,  it really worked.